# Search Excel sheet from ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, select

**UPDATE:**
I have found that this code works!  it searches the Excel sheet and only outputs the data I need.
But can anyone explain to me why this works?  how does it know that the first line in the spreadsheet is the "index"??

```
    //Coneection String by default empty  
    string ConStr = "";  
    //connection string for that file which extantion is .xlsx  
    ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "C:\\TestExcel.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';"; 
    //making query  
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [lol$] where ID='i2200'";  
    //Providing connection  
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);  
    //checking that connection state is closed or not if closed the   
    //open the connection  
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)  
    {  
        conn.Open();  
    }  
    //create command object  
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);  
    // create a data adapter and get the data into dataadapter  
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);  
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
    //fill the Excel data to data set  
    da.Fill(ds);  

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    lblud.Text = "" + row["Hylde"];
}
```

**OLD**
I have been trying to do this for several hours now but no matter what i try, I don't end up with the result i want.

So now im "starting from scratch" again. See if I have approached this incorretly.

Question:
I wan't to create a ASPX website that can search my excel sheet for specific data.
Something like `Select * from [Sheet1$] where Column A = i2200`

then display only Column B and C from that specific row into a Label / two labels.
See picture here: http://itguruen.dk/EXCEL.png

Does anyone have a simple way of doing this?
Thanks in advance!

Jasper

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about importing the Excel Spreadsheet into a DataTable, and then analyse that DataTable to populate your labels? You can perform SQL queries on DataTables, so you'll be able to extract the exact data you require quite easily (the hardest part will be importing the Excel Spreadsheet into the DataTable).

There's a very detailed report on this process here: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-and-Import-Excel-File-into-DataSet-or-DataTable-using-C-and-VBNet-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Yes I have thought about that, but I need to be able to edit the Excel spreadsheet from Excel.  that means, that everytime I make a change in the sheet, I would have to reimport the data on the website aswell.  I was just thinking, if there was a way to directly search and excel sheet, it would be the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

Update the post so you can see the solution.

Allthough I dont really know why this works??

Comment: I don't have Office so I don't have the drivers (couldn't get it to work). That said, check if this actually works on your server. What you've done is use Excel as your data source. In the connection string, `Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES` - [HDR=YES says first row contains column names, not data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500(v=vs.110).aspx). Hth...